# Egyptian walking onions; perennial how?

Tags: perennials, onions

Are Egyptian walking onions strictly perennial (by this I mean that the same plant base will regrow the next year) or only perennial in the sense that they fall over and replant the bulbils as “new” plants?

Comment: Welcome jcoleman to Gardening and Landscaping!

Comment: I had about a 75 ft row in zone 5 . They came back every year , I think from both the bulbs and top sets. The rabbits ate a lot of the leaves. in winter.  They were so strong I did not use them much so did not pay much attention to their growth.